# Find minimal lengh of a specific curve in $\mathbb{R}^3$

Tags: geometry, analysis

so a few months ago i competing in a math competion at university level,this competion has 3 types problem ,Analysis,Algebra and something that they called Creative type problem which i think they mean this problems can be solved using simple tools but they need creatively solution.

basically i know the solution of the problem which realsed after contest in other language and i will post it here if in case any one want to read it.

but my main question is

> does any body know other solution for this problem,or any book which included this question in it, or even any paper?

also if u know any other solution rather than the solution i posted i will be really greatfull if u share it with me thanks.

> Problem:Suppose $M$ is cube , with lenth of $1$ for each edge,and suppose $\gamma$ is a closed curve on the cube sides and touches all the sides(if curve touches an edge or a vertex it is also touches the sides which means if it is touch an edge it actually touchs $2$ sides at a time and if it touch a vertex it actually touch $3$ sides at a time). what is the minimum lengh of the curve?

it is so obvious the minimum lenth is $3 \sqrt2 $ but we need to proof it.
(i translated the solution and i know there is some mistakes in my translation so feel free to edit it)

Solution: without loss of genarality consider $[0,1]^3$ , and suppose $\gamma(t)=(\gamma_1(t),\gamma_2(t),\gamma_3(t)),0\le t \le 1$ for the desired curve.also we can approximately find the lenght using piecewise differentiable curve or polygon.so without loss of genarality we could assume $\gamma$ is a piecewise differentiable curve (or a polygon).

consider the projection of the curve on the $x$ axis we can write $\int _0^1 |\gamma^{'}_1(t)|dt \ge 2$. because the projection is continuous closed curve which cross from $0$ and $1$ so the minimum lenth is $2$.we get the same reuslt for $\gamma_2$ and $\gamma_3$.

also we know that curve touch the side of cube so for the differentiable points of $\gamma$ at least one of the $\gamma_i$ are $0$ using this fact and $\sqrt{a^2+b^2}\ge {{a+b} \over \sqrt{2}}$ we can write:

$$ \sqrt{ \gamma^{'}_1(t)^2+\gamma^{'}_2(t)^2+\gamma^{'}_3(t)^2 }  \ge {{|\gamma^{'}_1(t)}|+{|\gamma^{'}_2(t)}|+{|\gamma^{'}_3(t)}| \over 
 \sqrt 2}$$

taking integrate form both sides one can write:

$$\int _0^1 |\gamma^{'}(t)|dt \ge {1 \over \sqrt 2} \sum _{i=1}^3 \int _0^1 |\gamma^{'}_i(t)|dt \ge 3 \sqrt 2$$

so this is the minimal lengh and it is a triangle which include 3 diameter of cube with lenght $\sqrt 2$.

Comment: I think you meant *continuous simple* closed curve. Furthermore the solution does not make it clear why $3\sqrt{2}$ is the greatest lower bound.

Comment: @mucciolo yes that is indeed true.i am tried translate problem and solution without mistake. but as i said if anyone finds a mistake feel free to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

i) Assume that $\gamma$ is a simple closed curve touching six faces.

Consider the case : For $\varepsilon$, there is a sequence
$\gamma_n$ s.t. (1) $\gamma_n$ is in $\varepsilon$-tubular
neighborhood of $\gamma$, (2) a simple closed curve touching six
faces, (3) $$ {\rm length}\ \gamma'=\lim_n\ {\rm length}\ \gamma_n <
{\rm length}\ \gamma$$

where $\gamma'$ is a pointwise limit of $\gamma_n$, and (4)
$\gamma'$ is locally minimizing except finite points.

Then each projections of $ \gamma'$ onto coordinate planes has
length at
least $2$, by an assumption of $\gamma$.

ii) Assume that $\gamma'$ is in one face $F$ of cube. Note that it
is impossible, since
$\gamma$ can not go into opposite face of $F$.

Hence assume that $\gamma'$ is a closed curve of length
$2\sqrt{5}$.

That is, it can be explained by shortest curve passing through
$(0,0),\ (2,1)$ in a rectangle $$ R={\rm conv}\ \{ (0,0),\ (2,0),\
(0,1),\ (2,1)\}
$$ in
$xy$-plane. Here let $R=I\ \bigcup \ I+(1,0)$.

Here we have a claim that $\gamma'$ is one we will find.

iii) Here note that projections of $\gamma'$ in $I,\ I+(1,0)$ onto
$x$-axis must have length at least 2. And projections of $\gamma'$
in $R$ onto $y$-axis must have length at least 2. This completes the proof.